# Using Set does not remove duplicates when it's child is a list

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here I combine a HashMap with a array to produce combinations.
I sort the list using `line.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));` so that 
I have `[[1,0],[1,0]]` instead of `[[0,1],[1,0]]`

```
Set<List<int>> lines = new Set();
for (int key in _graph.keys) {
   for (int vertexKey in _graph[key].vertices) {
       var line = [key, vertexKey];
       line.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
       lines.add(line);
    }
}
```

**My Expected output is**

`{[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3],[0, 3]}`

**However, i get** 
`{[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]}`

Comment: Each of the members of the set will be different objects, and therefore not duplicates. The fact that the _elements_ of two of those objects are the same is – I believe – of no concern to `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is not a value type, and it does not override `operator ==`, so it will use the default [`Object.operator ==`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) implementation that checks only for object identity (i.e., whether two objects are the same instance).

In other words, two separate `List` instances will not compare equal even if they contain identical elements. `[0, 1] != [0, 1]`.

Even though `List` does not provide a deep `operator ==` implementation, you can override it by constructing a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet/LinkedHashSet.html) (`Set`'s default) or a [`HashSet`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-collection/HashSet/HashSet.html) explicitly and supplying your own `equals` and `hashCode` callbacks.  For example:

```dart
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart' show listEquals;
import 'package:quiver/core.dart' show hashObjects;

Set<List<int>> lines = LinkedHashSet<List<int>>(equals: listEquals, hashCode: hashObjects);
```

Comment: I am trying to replace 
`Set<List<int>> lines = new Set();`

with
`Set<LinkedHashSet<int>> linesHashSet = new LinkedHashSet(equals: listsEqual,hashCode: hashObjects);`

Is this the correct implementation?

Comment: @nishon.tan `Set<LinkedHashSet<int>>` doesn't make sense; that's a set of sets.  I've updated my answer for your specific case.